# org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate file name:

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am trying to create client project from WSDL file using Axis 1.4 (I don't have other choices, even cannot use Axis 2) and getting following error. Can any one suggest me how can I resolve it? The WSDL file is provided by vendor.

```
org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate file name: C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\CalculateTax\com\NewProj\CompanyCodeType.java.  
Hint: you may have mapped two namespaces with elements of the same name to the same package name.
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaWriter.generate(JavaWriter.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaBeanWriter.generate(JavaBeanWriter.java:1405)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaTypeWriter.generate(JavaTypeWriter.java:113)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.toJava.JavaGeneratorFactory$Writers.generate(JavaGeneratorFactory.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.generateTypes(Parser.java:547)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.generate(Parser.java:432)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser.access$000(Parser.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:362)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You might be experiencing [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2377).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there any way I can fix it? I mean by modifying WSDL code? Is it possible to fix Axis 1.4 bug by using Axis 2 code( I thought they fixed this bug in Axis 2). Please give me some inputs. I am stuck here and I don't have any other options too. I should use Axis 1.4 to generate Client code. Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Comment: You should inspect the WSDL and see if the issue can be pinpointed to specific line. Injecting Axis 2 code into older version is most likely not going to work. You might want to try using the latest 1.x version for generating your code, it should be compatible enough.

Comment: Hi Cebence, WSDL itself is complex. it has got included 34 schema files and real hard to dig which code is producing error. I am using SoapUI to figure out it but couldn't find the right place to hit. if you have any clue to focus on particular file, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Hi @NabRaj_Baitadi - were u able to solve this bit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to use Axis 2.

For example, if you have a part of wsdl like this:

```
  ...
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Town" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="leftSideOfAt" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="domain" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="OwnerAddress" type="tns:Address" />
  <xs:element name="EmailAddress" type="tns:address" />
  <xs:element name="CompanyEmailAddress" type="tns:address" />
  ...
```

This is a legal WSDL definition but Axis is failed. 
You can fix this problem with renaming complexTypes. For above example:

```
  ...
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Town" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Email">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="leftSideOfAt" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="domain" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="OwnerAddress" type="tns:Address" />
  <xs:element name="EmailAddress" type="tns:Email" />
  <xs:element name="CompanyEmailAddress" type="tns:Email" />
  ...
```

The point is when you write a name of complexType as "**PascalCase**", it conflicts with another one!

Answer (score 3):

The Axis 1.4 bug description is (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2606)

```
Hint: you may have mapped two namespaces with elements of the same name to the same package name.
```

Thus you can solve this by leaving out the optional parameter

```
-p, --package <argument>
    override all namespace to package mappings, use this package
     name instead
```

... and it will generate your WSDL classes without errors. You can refactor them later if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens when you try to generate java client using a wsdl with same element names. Please change the element names and try. Otherwise you can use the eclipse tool for generating java client. It will automatically detect the same element names and create separate packages for the same.
**To generate java client using Eclipse : Right click on wsdl file > Web Services > Generate Client.**
This should help you.