# Upgrading Axis1 to Axis2 in IBM Domino 9

Tags: java, wsdl, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm importing a wsdl file into IBM Designer but at the time I import it, it shows me the following error:

> The requested operation failed: Duplicate file name: C:\Users\Desktop...
>   Hint: you may have mapped two namespaces with elements of the same name to the same package name.

I have googled it for days, and as I can guess, it's a problem of Axis1 that doesn't occur with Axis2. The problem I have is IBM Domino because it has Axis1 and I don't know whether it's possible to upgrade it to Axis2. I have downloaded Axis2 and put it into `<NotesWorkspace>\framework\rcp\eclipse\plugins\` with the Axis1 version, of course it doesn't work.

I've been looking in File\Preferences tab of Notes/Designer but I have found nothing.

I must say I can't change the given wsdl file.

UPDATE: [WSDL and XSD files link](http://campusvirtualmtt.com/documentacion/ConsultaIdentidad)

Comment: Can you show the WSDL.  Also check this if you haven't  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025023/org-apache-axis-wsdl-tojava-duplicatefileexception-duplicate-file-name

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already read it, and maybe that's the solution, but I can't modify the wsdl nor the xsd files so I think I have to upgrade the Axis version, if it's possible... I've got the wsdl and 4 xsd. Do you want me to upload them anywhere?

Comment: You can save the WSDL to a file, modify it then generate the client files to test with.

Comment: Yes, I know. In fact, what I'm doing is importing the WSDL file into a Lotus Domino server, and that's where the problem lies, when importing. I can only make small changes to the WSDL or to the XSDs because it's an external WebService, and I'm consuming it to retrieve data from another server. So I guess the only way to achieve this is upgrading the Axis in the Lotus Domino server. I have updated my question with the WSDL and XSDs files. Hope this can help you, and thanks for your help.

Comment: The WSDL has no issues.  Try generating from a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have imported Axis2 framework into my project using java perspective and adding packages into WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder.
Then I didi the artifacts generation on my workstation, using 1.7 jdk.
All the generated files were imported into application (WebContent\WEB-INF\src).
In this way I could use all the code into a java class (Notes Designer) and use it as managed bean into a "xAgent".
The application was hosted on a Domino 8.5.3 Server.